# Send image to server Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

How can i send image from the client side to server?

i have a simple form like :

```
      <form>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SendImageToServer();" />
  <iframe id="uploadframe" name="uploadframe" src="upload.php" width="8" height="8" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</form>
```

And in the method i am using is :

```
          function sendImage(){
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

                  }

                 else
                  {
                   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                                //I want to get the response as simple <img scr="myimage"/>

             }
```

Can anyone help me how can i do this using Ajax-php.(NO JQUERY)?

Comment: As someone answered, posting to an `iframe` maybe your best bet.
However, I found an [Ajax Uploader](https://github.com/igstan/ajax-file-upload) that uses Firefox's File-Upload API.

Comment: @deed02392..i am just learning ajax..don't want to use jquery at the beginning..can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one thing you cannot send files with AJAX. But if you are submitting to an iframe, then the form needs to have enctype="multipart/form-data" defined, otherwise it does not submit files.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use AJAX term as you won't be creating one. To upload the file set an `action` and `target` on `form` and everything else should be automatic, that is, in-page.

```
<form action="upload.php" target="uploadframe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
... everything else here
<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Don't forget enctype="multipart/form-data" which is required to submit files.

Comment: i dont want to reload my page..just put an image on memory with ajax ..process it and get back the image...your ans is not even close to an understanding that you even know things...anyway...thanks for the junk reply

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju: Well, this is the half-way solution to your problem. You should probably be more specific in you question in future in order to expect the most accurate answers. Either way, depending on your server-side code (what does it return back) this could work just fine...